# Como compartilhar métodos entre presenters no Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, decorator-pattern

Gostaria de adicionar métodos ao meu modelo através de um Presenter, porém alguns métodos são compartilhados entre outros presenters.

```
Ex: os métodos 'pode_ser_mostrado?', 'pode_ser_editado?', 'pode_ser_excluido?'
```

Qual é a melhor maneira, criar um presenter base para ser estendido pelos outros?, ou criar um mixin incluído pelos presenters?

Exemplo:

```
class ModeloPresenter < BasePresenter
end
```

ou

```
class ModeloPresenter
  include 'base_presenter'
end
```

No caso como implementar?

Exemplo de como usar os métodos:

```
<%= link_to 'Mostrar', show_usuario(usuario.id) if UsuarioPresenter.pode_ser_mostrado? %>

<%= link_to 'Mostrar', show_cliente(cliente.id) if ClientePresenter.pode_ser_mostrado? %>

<%= link_to 'Mostrar', show_local(local.id) if LocalPresenter.pode_ser_mostrado? %>
```

Aceito também se houver sugestão de melhores maneira de implementar o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Fácil, fácil:

```
class MeuModelo << ActiveRecord::Base
  def pode_ser_mostrado?
    # implementação do método
  end
end
```

Comment: Pode elaborar melhor a resposta, caso ela realmente solucione o problema do OP?

Comment: ve se estar melhor explicado agora